# Is there any good information about Core Graphics for beginners?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics

Where can I find good information on how to use the Core Graphics iPhone library?
I've looked at the Apple documentation and I'm not really sure where to start.

Answer (score 2):

[Start here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_Graphics_iPhone/)

For information specifically about Core Graphics, excluding the other drawing-related APIs, [start here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/).

Answer (score 1):

[6 Resources For Learning Core Graphics](http://maniacdev.com/2009/09/6-resources-for-learning-core-graphics/)